How to creat chart use google apps script
I want to use google apps script to creat line chart, like below pic 1.
The x-axis from left to right is 0 to -90, the interval is -10, and the y-axis from bottom to up is 0, 100, 200 to 800, the interval is 100 actually.
The values ​​for the two curves from sheet. (pic 2 for example)
I tried to write code to creat but falied, could someone help me? Thanks a lot!


function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange1 = sheet.getRange("E10:AX10");
  var dataRange2 = sheet.getRange("E11:AX11");

  var xLabel = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 45; i++){
    xLabel.push(-2 * i);
  }

  var yData1 = dataRange1.getValues()[0];
  var yData2 = dataRange2.getValues()[0];


  var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable()
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'X')
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Line 1')
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Line 2')

  for (var i=0; i<xLabel.length; i++){
    dataTable.addRow([xLabel[i], yData1[i], yData2[i]]);
  }

  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  .addRange(dataRange1)
  .addRange(dataRange2)
  .setPosition(30, 5, 0, 0)
  .setOption('title', 'Graph')
  .setOption('hAxis', {
    title: 'X Label',
    viewWindow: {
      min: -90,
      max: 0
    },
    gridlines:{
      count: xLabel.length
    },
    ticks: xLabel
  })
  .setOption('vAxis', { 
    title: 'Y Label',
    viewWindow: {
      min: 0,
      max: 800
    },
    gridlines: {
      count: 9
    },
    ticks: [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800]
  })

  sheet.insertChart(chart.build());

}






In your showing chart, when the x is -10, it seems that the y is between 600 and 800. But, in your showing table, when x is -10, it seems that the values of y are 226 and 230. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the logic of obtaining this situation. I apologize for this. And, in your script, dataTable is not used. And, I cannot understand the relationship between dataRange1 and dataRange2 and your showing table. Can I ask you about the details of your situation? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Sorry for the confusion. This case is about throughput and attenuator test, when the attenuation rate (x axis) becomes lower (min -90), the throughput value (y axis, max 800, min 0) is getting bad. I can add a chart on my sheet by manually (as pic 1), but I have many sheets so I want to use google apps script to automatically create chart.
dataRange1 means throughput upload value;
dateRange2 means throughput download value

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to create a chart for Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.
The data is "A1:N3". I guessed that this is from your showing sample Spreadsheet.
You want to set the x-axis and y-axis to 0--90 and 0-800, respectively. And, the steps of the x-axis and y-axis are 100 and 10.

In this case, how about the following sample script?
Sample script:
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const chart = sheet.newChart()
    .asLineChart()
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("A1:N3"))
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .setNumHeaders(1)
    .setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true)
    .setOption("hAxis", { direction: -1, viewWindow: { min: -90, max: 0 } })
    .setOption("vAxes", { 0: { viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 800 }, gridlines: { count: 9 } } })
    .setPosition(5, 1, 0, 0)
    .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}


In this case, the steps of v-axis is 100. If you want to set it to 200, please modify gridlines: { count: 9 } to gridlines: { count: 5 }.

Testing:
When this script is run to your showing sample table, the following result is obtained. Your sample data is put into the cells "A1:N3".

Note:
Unfortunately, I do not know your actual situation. So, please modify the above script to your actual situation.
